# Makefile Error 1

Tags: bash, makefile

If I have this in a Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(RUN_INDEX),1)
    @echo Removing old index files...
    -rm *.*dx *.*nd *.ilg
endif
```

This always returns "Error 1(ignored)" unless there is at least one of each of the files with the extensions .dx, .nd, or .ilg.

Is there a way to avoid this or is it advisable to not ignore it?

Comment: Thanks lurker, this does it. Is there any way you could explain why?

Comment: @lurker if it works, I'd make an answer out of your comment and put some explanation in it.

Comment: Oops mistakenly deleted my first comment. The `-f` option on `rm` says "no flack" ... in other words, if it can't find the files to remove, it won't complain and won't return an error. However, I'm puzzled as to why the `-rm` isn't working for you. Can you show a bigger context in your makefile? What's the target and whole set of commands look like? I didn't really feel comfortable saying I answered the question without having some explanation as to why `-rm` isn't doing it for you.

Comment: That's fine: I wasn't sure if the whole thing is relevant but I've put it up in the OC. As far as I can tell only the parts surrounded RUN_INDEX should be relevant (near the end) but I've put the whole Makefile up just to be on the safe side. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah.... my bad. I see why the `-rm` wasn't doing it. I've provided a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-` prefix will ignore errors, but `make` will still write out a message that the error occurred. (See [this explanation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html).)

But you can use the `-f` flag on `rm`. This flag means "no flack": if `rm` can't find the file you want to remove, or has some other issue, it will not complain and just succeed anyway. And `make` will be none the wiser.

So change your makefile entry to this:

```
ifeq ($(RUN_INDEX),1)
    @echo Removing old index files...
    -rm -f *.*dx *.*nd *.ilg
endif
```